# Does performing unsigned operations on registers cause them to change their sign extension?

Tags: binary, byte, mips, bit

For example:

```
$t1 = 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0111
subu $t1, $t1, $zero
```

Would the register value in `$t1` change?

Answer (score 0):

No, it would not.

`SUBU` works just like `SUB` except that it doesn't trap on overflow.
From *MIPS32™ Architecture For Programmers
Volume II: The MIPS32™ Instruction Set*:

> The term “unsigned” in the instruction name is a misnomer; this operation is 32-bit modulo arithmetic that does not
>   trap on overflow. It is appropriate for unsigned arithmetic, such as address arithmetic, or integer arithmetic environments
>   that ignore overflow, such as C language arithmetic.

The same applies to `ADDU` and `ADDIU`.